# Google Maps API v2 cannot find Address Location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-geocoder

I'm using Google Maps Android API's `GeoCoder` Class for retrieving coordinates of a particular property from an Address String that I am giving it. But the android app can't find the Lat-Long of the property. Now, when I pass the exact same String to https://www.google.com/maps/, it is able to find the rooftop location of the property easily. It works in the mobile browser as well.

So what's going on? Why can't Google Maps find the property in my app? Here is my code below:

```
    LatLng propertyLocation = null;
    try {
        propertyLocation = getLocationFromAddress("Property Address");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    mOptions.position(propertyLocation).title("Property Location").snippet(propertyAddress)
            .draggable(true);

    propertyMarker = googleMap.addMarker(mOptions);
    propertyMarker.showInfoWindow();

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(propertyLocation, 15), 3000,
            null);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

And here is my `getLocationFromAddress();` Method:

```
private LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String subjectPropertyAddress) throws IOException {
    Log.i("Subject Property", subjectPropertyAddress);
    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        Geocoder addressCoder = new Geocoder(LocationActivity.this);
        List<Address> addresses = addressCoder.getFromLocationName(subjectPropertyAddress, 2);
        if (addresses == null || addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("Addresses", "Could not locate address:");
            return null;
        } else {
            Address location = addresses.get(0);
            return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("Geo-Coder", "Not Present");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with Asyntask class? Maybe, this code can help you

```
private class GeocodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx);
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {
        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            googleMap.clear();

            for(int i=0 ; i < addresses.size(); i++){
                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13f));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And search location :

```
new GeocodeTask().execute("Property Address");
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but it didn't work. Maybe, it's an issue with the GeoCoder?

Comment: What kind of Mapview you use in xml layout ? Is this : "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: Danh DC, yes it is `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`.

Comment: And your app loaded the map success, just have problem in function search location with GeoCoder ?

Comment: Since the GeoCoder cannot find the property location, it returns null, which causes the app to crash. But yes, otherwise the map loads successfully without any problem.

Comment: Hmm, GeoCoder still working good with me. Have you check the permission in manifest , try add 2 permission :                                          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: I already have these permissions. Please try this address in your GeoCoder: "805 N Crest Dr, Grand Junction, CO 81506"

Comment: Yup, this address not found. Have you try with another location, it still return null or just this address ?

Comment: Danh DC, just this address. Also, if you try searching this same address on the Google Maps website, Google will be able to find the exact location.

Comment: Hmm, I think have some difference between android and web version. The latest version of the Maps API for Android is v2, v3 is for the web

Comment: Hey @ADeveloper , i found the reason : in web , it use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro and android default use **GeoCoder** http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html